# Tengo un formulario que no realiza la última acción

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formularios

Me piden calcular las ventas y descuentos, además saber el valor total de ventas y el total de descuentos otorgados a las "N" ventas realizadas.

El método "calculcarFactura", calcula e imprime el resultado de cada venta en un formulario; después de "N" registros debería imprimir el total de descuentos y ventas pero el formulario nunca muestra el total de ventas y descuentos.

```
  private void btnConsultar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        calcularFactura();

        if (intCont < intNciclos)
        {               
            intCont = intCont++;                            
        }
        else
        {
            this.gpbVenta.Enabled = false;
            this.gpbTOTAL.Visible = true;

            this.lblTotalDescuentos.Text = Convert.ToString(dblTOTALDESCUENTOS);
            this.lblTotalVentas.Text = Convert.ToString(dblTOTALVENTAS);
        }
    }


    private void calcularFactura()
    {
        try
        {              
                  if (!validarCampos())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(strError, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        return;
                    }                        

                    objdatos.CantPro =Convert.ToDouble( this.txtCantidad.Text.Trim());
                    objdatos.ValorUnitario = Convert.ToDouble(this.txtValor.Text.Trim());
                    intNciclos = Convert.ToInt16(this.txtNciclos.Text.Trim());

                    if (!objdatos.Facturar())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(objdatos.Error, "Emm", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        return;
                    }

                    this.lblDescuento.Text =objdatos.Descuento.ToString("c");  //IMPRIMO COSTO 
                    this.lblSubtotal.Text = objdatos.Subtotal.ToString("c");
                    this.lblTotal.Text = objdatos.Total.ToString("c");

                    this.txtCantidad.Text = string.Empty;
                    this.txtValor.Text = string.Empty;                        

                    dblTOTALDESCUENTOS = dblTOTALDESCUENTOS + objdatos.Descuento;
                    dblTOTALVENTAS = dblTOTALVENTAS + objdatos.Total;                          


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Ups!",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sí no muestras que es lo que hace el método CalcularFactura(), entonces será muy difícil ayudarte

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta para que incluyas el código del método `calcularFactura` :)

Comment: Falta codigo en tu pregunta, no sabemos que tiene `intCont` ni `intNciclos`. En principio, tienes que pulsar el boton varias veces para que termine mostrando el total. De todas maneras, la forma segura de solucionarlo es que depures el codigo paso a paso y asi iras viendo porque nunca llega a mostrar los totales.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está en la manera que incrementas el contador:

```
intCont = intCont++;
```

Esto es equivalente a:

```
int a = intCont;
intCont++;
intCont = a;
```

por lo que intCont siempre tendría el valor inicial. Deja solo la sentencia:

```
intCont++;
```